# How node.js server behave if there is two request within same millisecond?

Tags: node.js, database, algorithm, concurrency, transactions

In which order node js server will serve requests if there are multiple requests at the same time?

How does it decide which request will be served first and what is the algorithm?

Comment: You have asked several questions. Please focus on one question only, and make it as specific and concrete as possible.

Comment: Yes @trincot, Hope it's clear now, could you please help me